# Hadoop Cluster Capacity Planning

Tags: apache-hadoop

I was doing some digging to get some deeper understanding on the Capacity Planning done for setting up a Hadoop Cluster.
I have a daily ~100 GB of data generated and would like to find how a Capacity planning needs to be done for it

```
Daily Input : 80 ~ 100 GB
Project Duration : 1 year
Block Size : 128 MB
Replication : 3
Compression : 30 %
```

It would be really helpful if you can guide me through and give me a good insight on how and what factors should be taken into consideration for the planning.